# How to remove block elements margins in mpdf?

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I noticed that block elements (ex. div) have some kind of margins by default, and it seems I cannot reset them via css. So how to? does anyone know?

Comment: Sure looks like margins cam be set via CSS: https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html

Comment: Sadly those docs are not reliable. Did you ever worked with mpdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, further investigation took me to the following findings:

Basically, you cannot use other than really simple/direct selectors. No nested selectors are allowed (like `.class p`, or `ul li`), so:

- think ahead and structure your document in a really simple manner so you don't have to use nested selectors or something more complicated. For example, do not use nested lists (`ul li ul`)
- write your css all with ultra simple direct selectors (one element or one class)
- then you can reset all the margins and paddings of block elements, if/when/where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Define your margin. E.g; you have class named as me. So browser is using own agent stylesheet.
What you have to do is to apply t margin to same class. Remember your CSS will override that.
So your code will look like .me {margin:0}. Then the margin will not be applied. Hope this helps

Comment: :) no this is an mpdf library-specific issue.